# Connection between UPS and server

Tags: networking, ups

I have bought a new [Server](https://www.dustin.no/product/5010885863/proliant-dl80-gen9) and [UPS](https://www.dustin.no/product/5010750618/smart-ups-c-1000va-2u-rm-lcd-230v) and am trying to find out if I need to buy an additional card (specifically, a network card) for the UPS and/or the server in order to manage the UPS, and allow it to shut the server down once the battery is low.

I have not used APC hardware before so am not familiar with setting them up.

(The server will be running CentOS.)

Comment: What makes you think you do? What have you tried in order to answer the question yourself before posting it here? What does this have to do with CentOS? We like questions to show evidence of own effort; please [edit] your question to show us why we should spend time answering this instead of some other question.

Comment: I added centos since thats the os i'm going to use on the server. as for the question, i have tried googling but i'm really new to servers to it was hard to phrase it correctly. And I didn't use that much time on the writing down the question, since I thought it would be a yes or no answer

Comment: We discourage answers that merely state "yes" or "no". For some discussion on the type of answers we encourage, see [How do I write a good answer?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer). The corresponding about writing questions is [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Super User is an English-only site.  Can you please try to find English versions of the product web pages you linked to?

Comment: Sorry. Here you go. [Server](http://www8.hp.com/no/no/products/proliant-servers/product-detail.html?oid=7500985). [UPS](http://www.apc.com/shop/th/en/products/APC-Smart-UPS-C-1000VA-2U-Rack-mountable-LCD-230V/P-SMC1000I-2U)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is 'no' the UPS you provided the link too has a built in NIC and USB port for management and controlling server shutdown etc.

You can connect the UPS to your existing network or connect directly to your server via USB (Provided you can get the software for your OS). Check the APC documentation and that should tell you the default IP so you can configure the UPS.

You don't say what you want to 'manage' but once the UPS is on the network you will be able to setup SNMP, email alerts and get access to the web portal of system settings (Voltage adjust, low battery warning time etc.)

With regards to having it shut down a server you have a couple of choices so should look at the software options on the APC site [here](http://www.apc.com/tools/download/index.cfm).